# How do I parse a sequentially organized multiline string into a data structure using regex/python?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need to parse a multi-line string into a data structure containing (1) the identifier and (2) the text after the identifier (but before the next > symbol). the identifier always comes on its own line, but the text can take up multiple lines.

```
>identifier1
lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala
>identifier2 
bababababababababababababababababa
>identifier3
wawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa
```

after execution I might have the data structured something like this:

`id = ['identifier1', 'identifier2', 'identifier3']`

and

```
txt = 
['lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala',
 'bababababababababababababababababa', 
 'wawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
```

It seems I would want to use regex to find (1) things after > but before carriage return, and (2) things between >'s, having temporarily deleted the identifier string and EOL, replacing with "".

The thing is I will have hundreds of these identifiers so I need to run the regex sequentially.  Any ideas on how to attack this problem?  I am working in python but feel free to use whatever language you want in your response.

****Update 1: code from slater getting closer but things are still not partitioned sequentially into id, text, id, text, etc ****

```
teststring = '''>identifier1
lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala
>identifier2
bababababababababababababababababa
>identifier3
wawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa'''

# First, split the text into relevant chunks
split_text = teststring.split('>')

#see where we are after split
print split_text

#remove spaces that will mess up the partitioning
while '' in split_text:
    split_text.remove('')

#see where we are after removing '', before partitioning
print split_text

id = [text.partition(r'\n')[0] for text in split_text]
txt = [text.partition(r'\n')[0] for text in split_text]

#see where we are after partition
print id
print txt
print len(split_text)
print len(id)
```

but the output was:

```
['', 'identifier1\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n', 'identifier2\nbababababababababababababababababa\n', 'identifier3\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
['identifier1\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n', 'identifier2\nbababababababababababababababababa\n', 'identifier3\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
['identifier1\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n', 'identifier2\nbababababababababababababababababa\n', 'identifier3\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
['identifier1\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n', 'identifier2\nbababababababababababababababababa\n', 'identifier3\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
3
3
```

***note:  it needs to work for a multiline string, dealing with all the \n's.  a better test case might be:***

```
teststring = '''
>identifier1
lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala
lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala
>identifier2
bababababababababababababababababa
bababababababababababababababababa
>identifier3
wawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa
wawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa'''

# First, split the text into relevant chunks
split_text = teststring.split('>')

#see where we are after split
print split_text

#remove spaces that will mess up the partitioning
while '' in split_text:
    split_text.remove('')

#see where we are after removing '', before partitioning
print split_text

id = [text.partition(r'\n')[0] for text in split_text]
txt = [text.partition(r'\n')[0] for text in split_text]

#see where we are after partition
print id
print txt
print len(split_text)
print len(id)
```

current output:

```
['\n', 'identifier1\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n', 'identifier2\nbababababababababababababababababa\nbababababababababababababababababa\n', 'identifier3\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
['\n', 'identifier1\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n', 'identifier2\nbababababababababababababababababa\nbababababababababababababababababa\n', 'identifier3\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
['\n', 'identifier1\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n', 'identifier2\nbababababababababababababababababa\nbababababababababababababababababa\n', 'identifier3\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
['\n', 'identifier1\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\nlalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n', 'identifier2\nbababababababababababababababababa\nbababababababababababababababababa\n', 'identifier3\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa\nwawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
4
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I feel that you should use regex as little as possible. It's slow, difficult to maintain, and generally unreadable.

That said, solving this in python is extremely straightforward. I'm a little unclear on what exactly you mean by running this "sequentially", but let me know if this solution doesn't fit your needs.

```
# First, split the text into relevant chunks
split_text = text.split('>')
id = [text.partition('\n')[0] for text in split_text]
txt = [text.partition('\n')[2] for text in split_text]
```

Obviously, you could make the code more efficient, but if you're only dealing with hundreds of identifiers it really shouldn't be needed.

If you want to remove any blank entries that might occur, you can do the following:

```
list_with_blanks = ['', 'hello', '', '', 'world']
filter(None, list_with_blanks)
>>> ['hello', 'world']
```

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: this seems quite elegant, but i think the partition part is not working.

Comment: @user391339 Ah, super tiny slip-up, the `r` should be removed. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood the question, it's as easy as

```
for line in your_file:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        id.append(line[1:].strip())
    else:
        text.append(line.strip())
```

Edit: to concatenate multiple lines:

```
ids, text = [], []
for line in teststring.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('>'):
        ids.append(line[1:])
        text.append('')
    elif text:
        text[-1] += line
```

Comment: hmm, that didn't work so far but maybe on the right track?  see updates to the question based on slater's answer.  your code gave me the following error - maybe i am not including something?  id.append(line[1:].strip())
NameError: name 'id' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

## **I found a solution. It's certainly not very pythonic but it works.**

======================================================================

======================================================================

```
teststring = '''
>identifier1
lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n
lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala\n
>identifier2
bababababababababababababababababa\n
bababababababababababababababababa\n
>identifier3
wawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa\n
wawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa\n'''

i = 0
j = 0

#split the multiline string by line
dsplit = teststring.split('\n')

#the indicies of identifiers
index = list()

for line in dsplit:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        print line
        index.append(i)
        j = j + 1
    i = i+1
index.append(i)  #add this so you get the last block of text

#the text corresponding to each index
thetext = list()
#the names corresponding to each gene
thenames = list()
for n in range(0, len(index)-1):
    thetext.append("")
    for k in range(index[n]+1, index[n+1]):
        thetext[n] = thetext[n] + dsplit[k]
    thenames.append(dsplit[index[n]][1:]) # the [1:] removes the first character (>) from the line
print "the indicies", index
print "the text: ", thetext
print "the names", thenames
print "this many text entries: ", len(thetext)
print "this many index entries: ", j
```

this gives the following output:

```
>identifier1
>identifier2
>identifier3
the indicies [1, 6, 11, 16]
the text:  ['lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala', 'babababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababa', 'wawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawawa']
the names ['identifier1', 'identifier2', 'identifier3']
this many text entries:  3
this many index entries:  3
```